# Code Coverage on Where method

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

I have a test method that's being analysed by Visual Studio 2012 Code Coverage, but I always get the result that the lambda in a Where method (or Any or ...) is reported as not covered

[image]

Anybody any idea to get this block covered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your list is empty.  In that case, the lambda will never run.  If the color of the highlight were yellow, I'd suggest that your lambda might not be evaluating both clauses because the `item.SourceCurrency` was always null.

Incidentally, `Assert.IsNotNull(exchangeRate)` will not test whether EUR is in the list as source currency, because (unless I much mistake) `Where` will always return an `IEnumerable`, even if the source `IEnumerable` is empty.  You need to test whether `exchangeRate` (and for that matter, `list`) has any members.